# Sending users an invite

Tags: forms

Need a solution to a problem I've been having.

I'm working on an internal corporate site. Users can be invited to the website via email and attached to a credit card.

A user can only be attached to one card but there can be up-to 6 cards to choose from. I need a solution for being able to send multiple users invites to the website and at the same time attach them to a credit card. (Attaching them to a card happens before the invite gets sent to the user)

Comment: Associate their email address to the chosen credit card and then send the invite to that email address?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a user experience problem.

Comment: Yes, somehow the user would have to input the email address of the person or people they wish to send the invite to. Then somehow select a card to attach them to.... possibly via a drop down?. Then hit 'Send invite' I'm not sure how to do this, or what the most effective way is?

Comment: @Reloaded I think you just described the solution. An input for the address and a dropdown for the credit card sounds reasonable. Do you see any issues with that?

Comment: Matt thanks for your reply. Where I see issues is if there are multiple email addresses attached to different cards. Do I have 5 fields for email addresses with drop downs beside to select the card. Then at the bottom have one CTA 'send invite' at the bottom? If I wanted to send a batch invites,as described above not sure how this would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest (as I think the OP did in comments) a simple list of email address and credit card pairs, with the option to add more recipients and a single button at the bottom to send the invites.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBeodH.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>